# Image is saving as tmp file in database laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Before explaining the problem. Let me show the controller function:

```
public function storePost(IdeaRequest $request)
{
   $idea = new Idea();
   $idea->idea_title       = $request->input('idea_title');
   $idea->user_id          = $request->input('user_id');
   $idea->idea_image       = $request->file('idea_image')->move('publicPages\images')->getClientOriginalName();
   $idea->idea_info        = $request->input('idea_info');
   $idea->selection        = $request->input('selection');
   $idea->idea_location    = $request->input('idea_location');
   $idea->idea_goal        = $request->input('idea_goal');
   $idea->idea_description = $request->input('idea_description');
   $idea->save();
   session()->flash('flash_message', 'Your idea has been submitted for Review');
   return back();
}
```

It stores the image as .tmp file. Things I have tried out

- `guessExtension()`, It just returns the extension name and does not
  even store the image.
- `getClientOriginalName()`, it throws an error;
  `getClientOriginalName` method is not defined. I have searched the
  method and it is in there. used its namespace
  `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`. it did not work
  either.
- Tried different things out from `stackoverflow`, Nothing has worked
  for me till now. In other words, i have invested a lot of time to
  solve this problem but nothing worked. Any help would highly be
  appreciated.

Comment: Try `$file = $request->file('idea_image');` then use `$fileName=$file->getFilename();` and see what you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public function storePost(IdeaRequest $request)
{
   $request->file('idea_image')->move('publicPages\images');
   $filename = $request->file('idea_image')->getClientOriginalName();

   $idea = new Idea();
   $idea->idea_title       = $request->input('idea_title');
   $idea->user_id          = $request->input('user_id');
   $idea->idea_image       = $filename;
   $idea->idea_info        = $request->input('idea_info');
   $idea->selection        = $request->input('selection');
   $idea->idea_location    = $request->input('idea_location');
   $idea->idea_goal        = $request->input('idea_goal');
   $idea->idea_description = $request->input('idea_description');
   $idea->save();
   session()->flash('flash_message', 'Your idea has been submitted for Review');
   return back();
}
```

Observe closely. You will have to do this in 2 separate lines:

```
$request->file('idea_image')->move('publicPages\images');
$filename = $request->file('idea_image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

**Why?**

> `move()` returns a `File` object representing the new file.

The `File` class doesn't have a `getClientOriginalName()` method. That method belongs to `UploadedFile`.

When you chain them, you are trying to access `getClientOriginalName()` from `File`, which doesn't exist. Have a look at the docs [here](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_move).

**However...**

[File](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) extends the PHP native [SplFileInfo class](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php) which has a `getFilename()` method. So I guess you could also do:

```
$request->file('idea_image')->move('publicPages\images')->getFilename();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man! I tried your given code and it worked but sometimes. I dont know why. When i changed these two lines   `$request->file('idea_image')->move('publicPages\images');`
   `$filename = $request->file('idea_image')->getClientOriginalName();` **to**  `$filename = $request->file('idea_image')->getClientOriginalName();`
           `$moveImage = $request->file('idea_image')->move('images', $filename);` loads of thanks again man :)